# How to iterate C# Enum Description attributes from a typescript 1.8 code

Tags: c#, typescript, enums

I have a web app that uses mvc c# and typescript code , I have a C# enumeration with descriptions.

```
MyEnum
{
    [First Value] FirstValue,
    [Second Value] SecondValue
}
```

I need to iterate that C# enumeration and get the Descriptions to add to a array in typescript - 
How can I accomplish this ?

**EDIT**
Now that I am at work I can post the full code - my question is relevant to typescript.

namespace Jobs {

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Serenity.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel;


[EnumKey("Order.Status")]   
public enum Status
{
    [Description("Order Active")]
    OrderActive = 1,
    [Description("Order Complete")]
    OrderComplete = 2
}
```

}

> How to iterate the enum above in typescript ?

TypeScript Code Follows:

```
export class OrderStatusEditor extends Serenity.Select2Editor<any, any> {

    private OrderStatusList: string[];
    private statName: Status;

    constructor(container: JQuery) {
        super(container, null);

  // Iterate the C# Enum Status
    for (var key in statName )
    this.addOption("key1", "Text 1"); 

}
```

In the above "Text 1" is the Description attribute on enum Status 
    "Order Active " and is not Status.OrderActive .

Comment: You can't do it in vanilla JavaScript, so you can't do it in TypeScript. You'll have to gather the descriptions on the server and send them to the client. How you go about doing that is up to you.

Comment: @krillgar - that is why I have a typescript tag and am asking specifically how to do this in typescript . please see my updated code example of where I am trying to do this.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. When you're within your TypeScript code, you don't have access to the server side code. Your TypeScript becomes vanilla JavaScript, which executes in the browser. That code has no clue about, nor does it care what code is executing on the server, let alone what language it is in. Like I said, you need to do that in C# and send the values to your TypeScript. You can't find that information out there.

Comment: @krillgar I appreciate your comment and information it does help me to understand a bit better. I am using serenity web application and my typescript knows about the enum - via an [EnumKey()] attribute - just new to typescript, mvc and learning how it works. I am probably going to need to look for where that attribute is defined in the library.

Answer (score 1):

Use Reflection. Hope this helps. Your question doesn't have a relation with typescript, remove the tag please

```
        private static string GetEnumDescription<TEnum>(TEnum item, string enumName) where TEnum: struct
        {
            Type type = item.GetType(); 

            var attribute =
                type.GetField(item.ToString())
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false)
                    .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
                    .FirstOrDefault();

            return attribute == null
                ? enumName
                    .FirstCharToUpper()
                    .ToSeparatedWords() 
                : attribute.Description;
        }
```

And the way to use it

```
var eType = typeof (TEnum);

foreach (TEnum eValue in Enum.GetValues(eType))
{
   var name = Enum.GetName(eType, eValue);
   var descp = GetEnumDescription(eValue, name );
}
```

Comment: please see the update of the question - you can see the relevance to typescript with the code where I show the typescript code file that I am trying to do this from. I need to iterate it in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably update your code snippet so it is valid C#. Take a real example from your code. Also give an example of the contents that you want the array to have, based off the example enum.

This sounds like a job for [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx). You can get the `Type` object of the enum and then discover everything you need to know about it and generate data to return to your client (presumably in a JSON array, in this case).

Comment: I am at work so I posted a real example. the c# side is not what I need - typescript which I have never worked with before is where I need the code to iterate it.

Comment: In your TS code it says: `private statName: Status;` - what does the declaration of `Status` look like? It must be in TS. Did you write it by hand or was it auto generated from the C# somehow?

Comment: thats my code writing trying to find out how this typescript works and see how I can get the attribute descriptions from the real Enum .. .

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. In order for you to use the identifier `Status` in your TypeScript code, it must have been declared in TypeScript. Where is that code? Did you write it or was it auto generated?

Comment: you were clear - I was not clear - I am new to type script and was thinking I was declaring my C# enum so I could get the description attribute. Serenity does a lot of building of the typescript in the background so that intellisense works in my C# code and also makes it available in my typescript code - which runs on the client side (I am not always sure how to access the c# code from there ) basically I have server side code that the client needs to know about. I guess if I can C# a string array and get access to it.

Comment: Okay in that case you should add a Serenity tag to your question as it is highly specific to that architecture and you need to attract any experts in it.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation yet to add a tag.
serenity-web